# Displaying Calcurse Notes on the command line in non-interactive mode

Tags: bash, command-line, calendar

[Calcurse](https://calcurse.org/files/manual.html) is a text-based calendar and scheduling application that is simple, light-weight, and highly effective. After a quick set up, I added my schedule (lectures and meetings) for a month (appointments, to-do, and notes) and wanted to create a bash-script that can read out the notes associated with each appointment (basically, the details of each lecture and some reference links) where a note file is a SHA1 hash of the note itself. I went through the documentation available [here](https://calcurse.org/files/manual.html) and tried the following on the shell :

`calcurse -a` gave me all the appointments for the day

`calcurse -t` gave me all the to-dos

`calcurse -at` gave me all the appointments and todos for the day.

However, as mentioned in the documentation the `-N` option should

> print note content if one is associated with the displayed item

When I run `calcurse -aN`, I do not get any output. I also tried the [Format-string](https://calcurse.org/files/manual.html#basics_format_strings) section but it *does not give me my notes associated with any appoinment*.

Please let me know if I should provide additional details. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Did you ask their mailing list?

Comment: Just emailed them a few hours ago. I did arrive at a peculiar solution that worked. Will put it up here asap.

Comment: @Ananth_Rao - do you still have that solution, or should we close this Question as "no longer needed"?

Comment: I found the solution after carefully reading through the documentation. Should I describe the solution here or should we close it?

Comment: I think am Answer here (in the Answer box) could be helpful to future readers; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To format the output in calcurse, the old documentation suggests we to use the `-N` flag. But according to version 3.0.0 :

```
The -N option has been removed in calcurse 3.0.0. See the Format strings
section on how to print note along with appointments and events.
```

So to format strings, you can use the format specifiers which are different for `appointment`, `event`, and `item` objects.

Examples are provided [here](https://calcurse.org/files/manual.html#basics_format_strings)